# Do crates share public static variables of common dependencies?

Tags: rust

Given three crates where two crates depend on one version of the third, and the third exposing a mutable static variable as part of its API.

Will modifications to a static variable made by one of the dependent crates be reflected globally? Does Rust provide a way to control this behavior?

Comment: One reason that globals are painful to deal with: the linker controls which gets used, not the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will modifications to a static variable made by one of the dependent crates be reflected globally?

Yes. The final rustc invocation by cargo will only add the shared dependency once. If you use two different incompatible versions of the shared dependency, then it will be added "twice".

> Does Rust provide a way to control this behavior?

I'm assuming you are asking whether it's possible to create a new static for every dependency using it. I'm not aware of such a feature. There might be hacks by going through dynamic libs, but there's no explicit feature that duplicates dependencies.

If you want such a behaviour, change the common dependency to yield a state object that the crates using it can put into their own static.